# The image in slider is repeating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web development and trying to build a website. In that website i want to build a slider. I have copied a featured slider from this link:

https://atbs.bk-ninja.com/ceris_technology/#atbs-ceris-offcanvas-mobile

The slider is working fine at large screen width but in small screen size width the main image is repeating but while dragging the Carousel it doesn't show problem.
How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try using css media query's to better fit your website in different sizes:

Like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

In this example the background would only turn lightblue in if the browser window is 600px os smaller.
You can use the same to make your image fit better in small sizes.